# What excel formula do I use to add all the weight with the same codes, without adding 00 and 000 together?

Tags: microsoft-excel

The answer that I should get is 17 for Code 000, while 6 for Code 00

| CODE | WEIGHT |
| --- | --- |
| 00 | 3 |
| 000 | 5 |
| 000 | 3 |
| 000 | 5 |
| 00 | 3 |
| 000 | 4 |

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SUMIFS will change all the `000` and `00` to `0` and thus match on all.  So we need to use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B2:B7*(A2:A7="000"))
```

The quotes are important.

One note:  This works if the numbers are stored as text and not numbers with cell formatting.  If the cell is formatted to show that number of 0 then formulas will not work as they look at the underlying value and not the cell format.

[image]

Comment: You're awesome! At first it won't work because I was trying to do B:B and A:A. But when I made it more specific on the cell numbers, it finally worked! Thank you.